# I couldn't mount my external ssd (ntfs) to my ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I tried something, but it's not working. For me, the `sudo fdisk -l` command gives me this output:

```
... loop devices removed from output ...

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: HFM256GDGTNG-87A0A                      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70A46181-6153-4C81-880E-3CB402E39E10

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem

...

Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: MobileDataStar  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FE0B84B3-6701-43B3-88E3-7D588DD4A495

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      34    262177    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 976771071 976506880 465.6G Microsoft basic data
```

I want to mount this /dev/sda which is a Netac external ssd.
Here is `lsblk` output:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop2         7:2    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop3         7:3    0 237.2M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2987
loop4         7:4    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop5         7:5    0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop6         7:6    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop7         7:7    0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop8         7:8    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop9         7:9    0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   238G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
```

The `sudo parted -l` gives me the output like:

```
Model: Netac MobileDataStar (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   500GB  500GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: HFM256GDGTNG-87A0A (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   256GB  256GB  ext4
```

After installing ntfs-3g, I tried this command `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda /media/ntfs/`:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I also tried this `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda` :

```
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda is not a mountable filesystem.
```

Tried `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs`
It's saying:

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sda2': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2021.8.22 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
        Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2021 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009-2020 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

Plugin path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ntfs-3g

News, support and information:  https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/
```

What can I do now?

Comment: I would think that you need to mount one of the partitions (/dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2), not the full disk-device (/dev/sda) - probably /dev/sda2,

Comment: I tried ```sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /media/```, it's saying: ```mount: /media: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist.
```

Comment: Your fdisk -l output shows that you have /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 - please verify !

Comment: fdisk -l ouput is showing this, but I couldn't find any sda1 or sda2 on my dev folder. And lsblk showing dev/sda only as a disk, no part.

Comment: And ```sudo parted -l``` is showing this: ```Model: Netac MobileDataStar (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   500GB  500GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata```

Comment: Please, edit your question and add this (very relevant) information, rather than putting it into a comment.

Comment: Was fast boot disabled when  the disk was unmounted from windows last time used there and was it unmounted cleanly ?

Comment: I have a desktop PC running windows, I can access the file, mount and unmount flawlessly in that, no problem in that. and the Ubuntu is in my laptop solely for linux.In that windows desktop, fastboot is disabled.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using ? Do you have ntfs-3g (or ntfsprogs for older releases) installed ?

Comment: I installed ntfs-3g now. Then i tried this command ```sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda /media/ntfs/``` and its saying: ```NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?```

Comment: Again, you are trying to mount the full disk device, not then tfs-partition ... as the error also suggest. Try `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs/` ...

Comment: tried it, saying no such file or directory

Comment: add the result in the post

Comment: I am out of ideas .. the strange thing is that parted shows two partitions on /dev/sda, but system (lsblk,mount, /dev/ ..) don't see them. Are there any errors in the logfiles, or in dmesg command when plugging the disk in? A little far out, but have you tried to reboot with the external disk plugged in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I installed gparted, then I change the flags of the partition, it was first on msftdata, I rechoose msftdta and close it. Then i saw my ssd is recognized and then I try the `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs` and it got mounted. Thank you everyone for your support.